# Delete row from database using OleDb

Tags: vb.net, row, oledb

I have this function working half right. The part that is working right is where I can select a row on the DataGridView, call this function using a "Delete Row" button, and then it will delete the row from the DataGridView....However, it does not delete the row on the database.

Can anyone help me with deleting the row from the DB using OleDb?

```
Function DeleteTableRow()
    Dim TaxConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Database")
    Dim dbConnection = New OleDbConnection(TaxConnStr)

    Try
        Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        Dim rdr2 As OleDbDataReader

        Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows

        dbCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM UserCriteria WHERE RowID =" & selectedRow
        If dbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbConnection.Open()
        End If

        dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection
        rdr2 = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


        rdr2.Close()

        '''Must select entire row to delete
        'DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).RowIndex))

        '''allows you to select on cell in the row to delete entire row
        For Each oneCell As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
            If oneCell.Selected Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex)
            End If
        Next



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataGridView.SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedrowcollection.aspx) is a collection of `DataGridViewRow`, you can't use a collection as a parameter to delete a particular and specific record on the database table. (Do you have [OPTION STRICT set tot OFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?)

You need to loop over the collection, get the correct `ID` value from every single row  and use that value as parameter to your delete query.

```
If dbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    dbConnection.Open()
End If

' Creating the command and its parameter here before entering the loop to avoid a continue'
' create and destroy pattern for the OleDbCommand'
Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
dbCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM UserCriteria WHERE ID =?"
dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row", 0) 
Dim rows = DataGridView1.SelectedRows
For Each row in rows
    dbCommand.Parameters("@row").Value = row.Cells("ID").Value)
    dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Pay also attention to not use string concatenation to build sql commands. This habit leads to a Whole can of worm called Sql Injection

Of course, an OleDbDataReader is not needed here. (Nothing to read about)

Comment: Corrections--- the column name in the database is just "ID". Also, on the DataGridView i have this column (the "ID" column) set to hidden. is this a problem?

Comment: No just change the code to reflect this fact. I will update the answer

Comment: Your For loop doesn't seem right. I have "For each selectedRow in Datagridview1.selectedrows" ...

Comment: Yes, right, copy,paste and translation from C# too quickly. Fixed

Comment: Still get an error that says "Column named ID cannot be found."...but i am staring at the DB. I see a column named "ID" in the UserCriteria table. ..

Comment: Do you get this error message when you step over the reading of the row or when you step on the execute command? And, by the way are you sure that the database pointed by the connection string is the same database you are staring at?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a reader to delete a row.  no data will be returned

```
   rdr2 = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


    rdr2.Close()
```

should simply be

```
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `DataGridView1.SelectedRows` will return a [`SelectedRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) (sorry, I've made the assumption this is a WinForms app). And that's not going to get you the correct result when passed to your `CommandText` because you'll probably get the ToString() of the `SelectedRowCollection` rather than the ID that you're after

What you actually want to do is loop over the collection (if the user is able to select more than one row) and delete each row that was selected, something like:

```
For Each selectedRow in DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    '1. Get the DatabaseId of the selected row
    '2. Modify dbCommand.CommandText to use the selected row from 1
    '3. execute command like you are doing with ExecuteNonQuery
Next
```

Each `selectedRow` in the above will be of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx) type...which has a `Cells` property you can access to get the ID you need (I am not sure which cell it will be in but you should be able to tell from your code).